# getting total sum when trying to sum a variable using multiple groups

Tags: r

I'm trying to sum a variable using multiple groups but keep getting the total sum, tried dplyr, data.table and aggregate, but I keep getting the total sum, instead of group sums.

The last effort was with `as.data.table`

```
Totals06 <- as.data.table(testQ)[, sum(testQ$v23, na.rm=TRUE), by = .(testQ$v01, testQ$v05, testQ$v09)]
```

I'm doing something really dumb, any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: I think that `?tapply` will help you.  I say I think because I am not totally clear on your problem and [a self contained reproducible example](https://www.tidyverse.org/help/#reprex) will help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Due to lack of reproducible example, here is a toy example:

```
df = data.frame(a=c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C"),species=c("cat","cat","dog","cat","dog","dog","horse","dog"),exp=c(1,2,3,4,5,3,2,1))

>df
#  a species exp
#1 A     cat   1
#2 A     cat   2
#3 A     dog   3
#4 B     cat   4
#5 B     dog   5
#6 C     dog   3
#7 C   horse   2
#8 C     dog   1
```

using `dplyr` and grouping by two variables:

```
df%>%group_by(a,species)%>%summarise_at(.funs = sum,.vars = c("exp"))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   a [?]
#       a species   exp
#    <fctr>  <fctr> <dbl>
#1      A     cat     3
#2      A     dog     3
#3      B     cat     4
#4      B     dog     5
#5      C     dog     4
#6      C   horse     2
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I was not using summarise_at just summarise, that seems to have done the trick!

Comment: @MichaelLatner Even `summarise` works for me. `dplyr` version 0.7.4 .